# How to run shell script without sh or bash in Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, shell-script, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running ubuntu using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). I have written a simple shell script below. When I run it gives the below error.

```
#! /bin/sh
# "test script"
echo "hello world"
```

> test.sh: command not found

But it runs successfully If I run the using command `sh test.sh` or `bash test.sh`.

So is there any way I run without `sh` like the native Linux?

Comment: Not really any difference than normal Linux - Remove the space so that it is `#!/bin/sh` and then `chmod +x test.sh`.  Also, it needs to be executed with `./test.sh` if it is not in the path.

Comment: Refer to this may this helps you. https://www.webservertalk.com/run-sh-files-in-linux-and-windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always run it as `./test.sh`.

`./` resolves to current directory ending with `/`, so you're effectively providing the full path to your script.

Just `test.sh` will work only if your current directory is in `$PATH`. This isn't exclusive to WSL.

Comment: It's working, but why and how? please explain the concept

Comment: @viveknuna [Why do we use `./` to execute a file in Linux/UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4430/108618)

Answer (score 3):

Basics:

**First:**
You create a script with a "shebang" on the first line, this defines if it is e.g. bash, python or perl which understands the remainder of the text file.

This usually looks like: `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/bin/env python` or some such

**Second:**
Make sure the file has the `x` -flag for a selection of `user`, `group` and/or `others`  (`man chmod` for more detail) by use of e.g.
`chmod 755 script_filename`

**Third:**
Place it in a folder (directory) on your harddisk, on any permanently mounted storage medium.
Here `mkdir -p $HOME/bin/` might be a good idea, for personal stuff.

**Fourth:**
make sure the folder is stated in `echo $PATH` - by e.g. adding a line containing
`export PATH=$PATH:/absolute/path/to/folder/`
in `$HOME/.bash_aliases`

With all these in place your script will be accessible (executable) - *in a newly launched shell (for #4 to take effect)* - by only typing the name at the bash prompt.
*(Note: WSL at least in first incarnation, is/was an Ubuntu by Canonical)*

---

More detail: https://tldp.org/guides.html - in the Bash guides